# ArrayAdapter causes emulated mobile application to crash

Tags: java, android

Trying to load a page that only contains a listview listing some keys of a firebase realtime database. Currently, once the page loads, the emulated mobile app crashes and I have no idea why.

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:id="@+id/terms"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Java:

```
        DatabaseReference termsReference = database.getReference("users/"+userID+"/terms");
        ArrayList<String> terms = new ArrayList<String>();

        termsReference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for(DataSnapshot singleSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                    terms.add(singleSnapshot.getKey().toString());
                }

                ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, terms);
                listViewTerms.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

            }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            }
        });
```

The terms arraylist only contains one string, so terms = ["term1"]

What I've found is that the app doesn't crash when I comment out the following lines:

```
ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, terms);
                listViewTerms.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
```

but I need those lines, so I'm kind of stumped. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Your question title says that you are crashing Android Studio.  The question body says that the app is crashing.  Which of those is correct?  (It can't be both!!!)

Comment: @StephenC Sorry fixed the wording. The application within the emulated device is what's crashing.

Comment: You haven't fixed it.  "ArrayAdapter causes emulated mobile application to crash Android Studio Java".  That still says plainly states that the application is crashing Android Studio.  Hint: you don't need to put keywords into the title.  That's what tags are for!!

Comment: Also ... you need to add the complete stacktrace to the question.   Without the stacktrace, there's no way to know for sure what the actual problem is.

Answer (score 0):

Forgot to properly initalize listViewTerms. Added `listViewTerms = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.terms);` into the Java method.